# puzzling behavior of `.[]|=empty`

Tags: jq

As far as I understand, the use of `empty` in update-assignment `|=` deletes the entry, similar to `del(path)`, and `del(path)` also works in arrays.

I tried to selectively delete and modify array entries, and got strange results. While trying to understand the problem, I minimized the code to this:

**Filter**: `.[]|=empty`
**Input**: `[0,1,2,3,4,5]`
**Output**:
`[
  1,
  3,
  5
]`

Try it online [here](https://jqplay.org/s/rBMHdN4H0w)

Apparently, only even array indexes are deleted. Why?

Comment: Interesting. The output in `jq` 1.5 (which until now I thought was the most recent version) is `null`, while `jqplay.org` is using the recently released 1.6 version. I could *imagine* that `|=` and `empty` are each consuming their own element from the input (`empty` takes 0, `|=` takes 1, etc), but whether 1.5 or 1.6 is "correct", I couldn't say. (That is, it could be a bug fix or a regression in 1.6.)

Answer (score 1):

As noted in a comment, jq's treatment of `.[] |= empty` has varied over time.  One might expect that for every array, A, `A | (.[] |= empty)` would yield `[]` on the theory that the expression should result in every item in A being replaced by `empty`.

In any case, the current (jq 1.6) implementation is clearly wrong, as is particularly noticeable in this example:

```
jq-1.6 -n  '[0,1,2,3] | (.[] |= if . == 2 then empty else . end)'
[
  0,
  1,
  3,
  null
]
```

Bug reports can be submitted to https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues

Comment: Thanks @peak for the example.   
I've used a variant in the [jq GitHub issue](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1771)